# IntelliJ IDEA "Cannot resolve method" on aspect-defined method

Tags: intellij-idea, aspectj, spring-aspects

I am using [spring-data-neo4j 3.4.2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/tree/3.4.2.RELEASE), which is (optionally) using AspectJ.

My IDE is IntelliJ IDEA 16 (EAP, IU-144.3891.8). I have had the same problem using latest IntelliJ IDEA 15.

Everything works fine so far within IntelliJ, I can compile, run my Unit-Tests, deploy and run my web-application to/on Wildfly and so on.

When building my project in IntelliJ, I can see usage of the required aspects (the following warning is ok).

```
org.springframework.data.neo4j.aspects.support.node.Neo4jNodeBacking has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
...
```

**My problem**: IntelliJ IDEA uses the spring-aspects/ajc correctly. But **in the editor, the aspects are not resolved/used**. Code-completion etc. does not work.

[image: IntelliJ editor error message]

At AspectJ-facet configuration, aspect-path is configured [as suggested](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/tree/3.4.2.RELEASE).

[image: AspectJ facet configuration].

Plugins "AspectJ Support" and "Spring AOP/@AspectJ" are installed and active.

[image: installed aspectj plugin]

I would like to use the spring-(data-)aspects in my editor, any suggestions, how IntelliJ Editor can get aware of the apsects?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of [open AspectJ-related tickets](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=%23AspectJ+%23Unresolved+) for IDEA. They have not been resolved for a long time. I love IDEA, but when it comes to AspectJ support Eclipse is superior, probably because AspectJ is an Eclipse project. So whenever I am dealing with AspectJ, I normally use Eclipse, as much as I would like to do everything in my favourite IDE IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Sad to hear this, but thanks for this information. I guess it's time for an additional bug-report.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by adding the following maven dependency. None of solutions worked for me which were given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137020/package-doesnt-exist-error-in-intellij). Another solution is here.

Maven Dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aspects -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Hope this fix will help other users too.

Answer (score 0):

From `pom.xml` remove the `<runtime>` tag from the dependency of `aspectjweaver` and `aspectjrt` and compile the `pom.xml` file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.7</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to project structure -> Dependencies -> and then make all dependencies compile time.