# Intellij maven indices folder size is huge

Tags: intellij-idea

I found that folder .IdeaIC2016.3\system\Maven\Indices\ have 60GB of data, can I clean it up? I already run https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/cleaning-system-cache.html but it doesn't help

Answer (score 2):

Asked at jetbrains forum, I can just delete it https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000084304-Intellij-maven-indices-folder-size-is-huge

Answer (score 0):

I read on Jetbrains forum also that I can delete folder, however after that IDEA was unable to resolve dependencies, just as described here : [Package doesn't exist error in intelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137020/package-doesnt-exist-error-in-intellij)