# JavaDoc error: reference not found * @throws MessagingException Check the method prepareMail()

Tags: java, exception, javadoc

Good morning Community.

I am facing an error generating a JavaDoc for my project. I tried to look it up but it didn't give me any solution for it so far. Hopefully one of you can help me on that.

```
C:\...\SendFileEmail.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
public static void sendTestMail() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, 
                                        UnsupportedEncodingException, MessagingException {
                                                                      ^
symbol:   class MessagingException
location: class SendFileEmail

C:\...\SendFileEmail.java:60: error: reference not found
 * @throws MessagingException Creating the email message.
   ^
```

I am sure that I added the jar to the path because the program works without problems.
Do you have any advice on that? What am I missing?

EDIT 1: I am using Intellij IDEA 2017.1.5 and Java 8

EDIT 2: I was doing some more research and I stumbled over this question on SO [Package doesn't exist error in intelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137020/package-doesnt-exist-error-in-intellij) so I started looking deeper in all the settings I can make for my project and I found a dependency tab. Added some libraries to that one and long story short I fixed my problem. Thanks for your help :)

Cheers, Julian

Comment: Could you add the command used to generate the JavaDoc or are you triggering JavaDoc generation from IntelliJ?

Comment: I use "Tools > Generate JavaDoc..." from Intellij