# Idea Intellij: Can't import the libraries: package does not exist

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import, dependencies, package

I'm trying to make use of a [jReddit](https://github.com/jReddit/jReddit) library, which, in turn requires [apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) and [Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) libraries.

I downloaded the sources, added them in Itellij Idea through File - Project Structure - Modules - Add Content Root.

All the classes from the libraries that my code makes use of are imported successfully. But the problem appears when compiling - it says that `package com.github.jreddit.oauth does not exist` and `package org.apache.http.impl.client does not exist` and that it `cannot find symbol` of those libraries' classes.

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

Comment: Why aren't you using maven?

Comment: @Oleg, I never used it before..

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137020/package-doesnt-exist-error-in-intellij. And I agree with @Oleg - cosider using `maven` or better `gradle` to build your projects

Comment: @IvanPronin Which one is better is extremely debatable. From my personal experience it's much better to use `maven`.

Comment: Well, gradle can do everything that maven can + adds far more features +it uses groovy (endless flexibility) + requires less efforts to do the same things with maven. Maven becomes outdated nowadays.

Comment: @IvanPronin All those points can be disputed, this is really not the place for such a discussion. You can read https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/5eoxxp/gradle_vs_maven_current_thoughts/ and just assume that I said everything that people arguing for maven said. For what OP needs it really doesn't matter which build  tool he will use, unfortunately he received some bad advice from a high rep user telling him not to use one.

Comment: @Oleg, Hey, I'd take your advice into consideration, it's just I really need a quick solution for now, but I do intend to learn maven later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Maven or Gradle if you can't even manage adding a JAR to your project manually.

You should acquire those JARs (containing .class byte code files, not .java source), add them a folder in your project named /lib, and add that directory as a JAR source location in your project. They'll be in the CLASSPATH then.

You need to add the /lib folder to an artifact when you run.  Be sure you know how to do that as well.

Comment: So I need to first compile all the libraries that I need?

Comment: Compile?  No, download the JAR, not the sources.  It's all compiled for you.  Just add to the CLASSPATH as I told you.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error after upgrading IntelliJ to version `2019.1`. These steps fixed it for me:

1. Click `Run` from the toolbar
2. Choose `Edit Configurations`
3. Make sure the Scratch file you want to run is selected on the left panel
4. In `Use classpath of module` dropdown, select the project module that contains the proper module