# JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA Remove Manifold Plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, manifold

I installed the Manifold plugin for IntelliJ IDEA, but then we decided we don't need it.

I'm using a Mac.

How the heck do I remove it?
It gives me a bunch of errors like `java: package manifold.internal.runtime does not exist` for each file.

Comment: Can you describe the problem/errors you have with Manifold?  I can help you to resolve them.

Comment: @Scott I installed Manifold into IntelliJ perfectly with the JARs and plugin.  It compiled and ran.  But now, I tried to delete manifold.  I deleted the JARs and disabled the plugin.  But now it gives the mentioned error for each file.

Comment: Can we take the discussion to the Manifold github repo as an issue? (https://github.com/manifold-systems/manifold/issues).  In any case the IJ plugin should simply uninstall/disable via `Settings | Plugins | Manifold`.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137020/package-doesnt-exist-error-in-intellij? -- @Scott this is not a manifold-specific issue, per the linked question it happens to any package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the plug-in manually from the [plug-ins directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519).

On macOS for IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1 version that would be:

`~/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2019.1`

Comment: Hmmm.  I deleted `manifold-ij` from the mentioned directory, but when I restarted IntelliJ it didn't change anything :(.

Comment: Check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for errors. Do you see the plug-in still loading? If not, where do you get the errors? Try creating a new project. You may have the imports for these classes in your code, but the dependencies can be missing, remove the usages from the code and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am working on the same project as the OP.

What worked for me was running `find -type f | xargs grep -i manifold` (find all files that case-insensitive contain `manifold`), and manually deleting the references. After doing that, the error disappeared.

Comment: ```find: illegal option -- t
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]``` . What does this mean?

Comment: It searches for all files (`-type f`) -- I have GNU (coreutils iirc) find, which you likely don't have on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Close IntelliJ IDEA, then delete the folder of the plugin from your filesystem in `$HOME/.IntelliJ2018.x/config/plugins`.

Comment: I don't have a folder `.Intellij2018.x`.  Should I create it?

Comment: @mackycheese21 I believe the `x` represents any number, so you should look for the folder corresponding to the version of IntelliJ you have, likely `2018.3` or `2019.1`

Comment: @NoOneIsHere, I'm sorry but I have no file that starts with `.Intel` in `$HOME`.  I pressed tab after typing `cd $HOME/.Intel` and nothing came up.

Comment: @mackycheese21 I have a folder called .IntelliJIdea2018.3, but I'm on Linux. I'd expect it to be somewhere else on OSX.