# java package <package> does not exist

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox for a little project but I'm getting a package does not exist error when compiling. As for the IDE, I followed the instructions to add modules and was able to import them. I would appreciate some ideas to fix the issue. Thanks!

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.util.Map.entry;

public class TextAnalyser {
....
```

**Output**

```
./TextAnalyser.java:1: error: package org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel does not exist
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
                                ^
./TextAnalyser.java:2: error: package org.apache.pdfbox.text does not exist
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
                             ^
./TextAnalyser.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
                PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(fileName));
                ^
  symbol:   class PDDocument
  location: class TextAnalyser
./TextAnalyser.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
                PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(fileName));
                                      ^
  symbol:   variable PDDocument
  location: class TextAnalyser
./TextAnalyser.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
                PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                ^
  symbol:   class PDFTextStripper
  location: class TextAnalyser
./TextAnalyser.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
                PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                                                  ^
  symbol:   class PDFTextStripper
  location: class TextAnalyser
6 errors
```

**EDIT**
I solved by rebuilding. Post [Package doesn't exist error in intelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137020/package-doesnt-exist-error-in-intellij)

Comment: Please check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency. Make sure you have either the jars added to the dependencies or you have a module with the sources added there.

Comment: What kind of project is it? Maven?

Comment: @AndreyLebedenko how can I tell? Sorry, maybe I'm trying to do something beyond my skill...