# Intellij Maven Dependency is not able to imported

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to import dependency with maven to Intellij.
And I edited pom.xml like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
        <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0_214</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jcenter</id>
        <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
        <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

and I checked if dependencies are well added.
[image: Dependencies list]

And I wrote below code in my project.

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.*;

public class main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {}
}
```

The result is.. I got error: *java: package net.dv8tion.jda does not exist*
I did maven Reload project and Invalidate caches and I still getting same error.
I wonder why this happens and how to fix.

Comment: which version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: According to Ahmed Salem's answer for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137020/package-doesnt-exist-error-in-intellij there is a bug in IntelliJ version 2020.1 and 2020.1.1

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me:
File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart, then Build -> Rebuild project

I could then import JDABuilder or other classes.