# mvn install throws error "Pacakage ... does not exist" even though it exists

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm getting a compilation error when building a java project with instances of classes in `client-a` being using in `controller`:

```
/path/to/file/project/controller/Config.java [50,1] package com.stuff.clienta does not exist
cannot find symbol ClientAClass
```

So I recently added two new modules to a multi-module java project using Maven. `module-a` & `client-a`. Such that `module-a` is dependent on `client-a`. This project also has existing modules, and there is one "master" module that initializes all the beans in the project called `controller`, thereby, `controller` is dependent on `client-a`.

When running `mvn install` I get the error only on references to files in `client-a` in `controller`. `module-b` builds fine.

I've gone through all the answers here ([Maven, package does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213923/maven-package-does-not-exist)) and wasn't able to get past this issue.

Additionally, in the `controller` pom, I added the dependency as such

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stuff.clienta</groupId>
            <artifactId>client-a</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

the exact same way as it is in `module-a` and I confirmed maven reactor is working because with this dependency, `client-a` gets built first, without, `client-a` gets built at the end.

Additionally, the parent pom has `client-a` as a dependency in the dependencyManagement section:

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.stuff.clienta</groupId>
                <artifactId>client-a</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
```

Any guidance would be helpful. At this point I don't really think it's related to the pom, but something in the build. I've tried deleting the `target` folders and the `.m2` folders (for just this project) then rebuilding but I get the same problem...

EDIT:
parent pom info

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>controller</module>
        <module>module-a</module>
        <module>client-a</module>
    </modules>

    <groupId>com.stuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>root</name>
    <description>Stuff</description>

    <properties>
        ... versions
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.stuff</groupId>
                <artifactId>controller</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.stuff</groupId>
                <artifactId>module-a</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.stuff</groupId>
                <artifactId>client-a</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                ... springboot, mojo, checkstyle
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            ... jacoco, checkstyle, maven
        </plugins>
        <extensions>
            ...
        </extensions>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: If this is a multi-module maven project, can you share the parent pom as well?

Comment: @ManeeshaIndrachapa I added the parent pom, I had to remove some info but let me know if there's anything specific you'd need and I can share.

Comment: in the parent pom in child module section put child modules in order you want to build, as an example if module B is a dependency of module A, put module B first then module A, because it can also cause an issue.

Comment: yeah I tried that too and it didn't help :/ I'm not sure if this helps but when I run the spring app I don't see the endpoints on Swagger either

Comment: Maven automatically determines the order, you do not need to order the modules.

Comment: Double-check the work that maven is doing.  Make sure it is picking up the JAR files from the expected places.  It could be something non-obvious, such as having the wrong parent pom version number in the module's pom.  `mvn -X` may help.

Comment: @ash that did the trick. I was looking for the classpath and this gave me that info! Looks like it was looking for the files in the target folder of the dependency. That folder was empty. I built it via intellij and mvn install worked! ... Now I wonder why it didn't build like that default 

Comment: Adds the client-a pom.xml to your question.

Comment: @capa_matrix if I understand correctly, that building via mvn didn't compile the sources, confirm the `packaging` type for the module is either the default or `jar`

Comment: yeah the packing on all the poms is default except for the parent pom where it's "pom" @ash Basically I run mvn clean install or clean package it fails. Then I have to manually package the module of client-a before the install or package works. It's so weird. I also tried changing branches (on a working branch) and building and it gave this strange problem which I've never seen before...