# IntelliJ can't find Maven dependency even though it exists

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ and I'm trying to build a Java project using Maven. However, IntelliJ keeps giving me an error that it can't find one of my dependencies, **io.jsonwebtoken**, even though I know for a fact that the dependency exists in my Maven repository. And I can go to the class definitions from Intellij [class definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAYSU.png) and there are no errors in any of my classes [no errors in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELHXd.png)

I've tried refreshing the dependencies in IntelliJ, invalidating caches and restarting, and even deleting the .m2 folder to force a redownload of all the dependencies. But nothing seems to work.

The error message I'm getting is:[build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoEP0.png)

I've double-checked that the dependency is spelled correctly in my pom.xml file, and that the version number matches the version in my repository. I'm not sure what else to try.

Any ideas on what might be causing this issue, or how I can resolve it? Thanks in advance!

this is my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>API</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.paulschwarz</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-dotenv</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Check this out - might be related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137020/why-does-intellij-give-me-package-doesnt-exist-error
Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213923/maven-package-does-not-exist

Comment: thank you. i followed this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42829251/9688188 from the above answers. it worked this time, even though i tried invalidating the cache before and it didnt work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does IntelliJ give me "Package doesn't exist" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137020/why-does-intellij-give-me-package-doesnt-exist-error)